# NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event stops working

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, networking, wmi

I am using this simple way to detect network connect/disconnect events:

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged);
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);

...

static void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
{
    RaiseNewtorkChange();
}

static void NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RaiseNewtorkChange();
}

static void RaiseNewtorkChange()
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that sometimes `NetworkAddressChanged` event just stops working, after it was fired several times. Does anyone have an idea why this can happen?

Alternatively, is there another way to handle network connect/disconnect events, using C# or C/C++. Maybe there is such functionality in Windows API or WMI? I need notification on LAN/WiFi network connecting/disconnecting, without polling.

Comment: FWIW, the most likely reason that you're seeing it "just stop working" is because there's an exception being thrown somewhere in the `RaiseNetworkChange()` handler (and any downstream code). Why?  Read this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/589409/notification-of-static-networkchange-networkaddresschanged-event-is-delayed-or-never-received

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to use the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Take a look at the function [WlanRegisterNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), in particular this notification:

> **WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM:**
>  Registers for notifications generated by the auto configuration module. 
>   Windows XP with SP3 and
>   Wireless LAN API for Windows XP with SP2:  Only the
>   wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete and
>   wlan_notification_acm_disconnected notifications are available.

*Disclaimer: I have used Native Wifi API in the past, but I have never used this particular feature.*

Comment: Thanks, this may help for WiFi, but I am looking for generic solution for all network types, including LAN.